# while calling a method multiple times,some data are missing while using django rest serializer?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, serialization

serializer.py

The get_invoice_list method calling invoice_date() multiple times but some data are missing,while i trying to convert invoice_list into dict ,

```
class InvoiceDetailSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    invoice_list = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_invoice_list(self, obj):

        invoice_list =[]
        if obj.get_invoice_users.all():
            first = False
            second = False
            third = False

            reg_invoices = obj.get_invoice_users.all().filter(type__in=[0,1]).order_by('created_date')            
            if reg_invoices:
                inv_string = 'INV'+str(obj.get_invoice_number)+'001'
                new_list1 = self.get_invoice_data(reg_invoices, inv_string)
                invoices_list.append(new_list)
                first = True                

            hotel_invoices = obj.get_invoice_users.all().filter(type__in=[3,5]).order_by('created_date')
            if hotel_invoices:
                second = True
                if first:
                    inv_string = 'INV'+str(obj.get_invoice_number)+'002'
                else:
                    inv_string = 'INV'+str(obj.get_invoice_number)+'001'
                new_list2 = self.get_invoice_data(hotel_invoices, inv_string)
                invoices_list.append(new_list2)
        return invoices_list       
    def get_invoice_data(self, inv_list, inv_key):

        invoices_list = []
        reg_invoices_list = []
        index=0
        new_dict = {}
        for index, each_invoice in enumerate(inv_list):

            new_dict['first_name'] = each_invoice.users.user.first_name
            new_dict['invoice_number'] = inv_key
            return new_dict
```

view:

```
class InvoiceDetailViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = InvoiceDetailSerializer
    queryset = EventUsers.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [AllowAny, ]
```

response :

Now i am getting response like this,

```
[ 
 {
        "invoice_list": [
            {
                "invoice_number": "INV013001",
                "first_name": "546546",

            },
            {
                "invoice_number": "INV013002",
                "first_name": "546546",

            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want the second dict ie "invoice_number": "INV013002" as another
dict not in an arrey how can i done that,

```
[
    {
    "invoice_list": [
        {
            "invoice_number": "INV013001",
            "first_name": "546546",

        }
    ]
},
{
    "invoice_list": [
        {
             "invoice_number": "INV013002",
              "first_name": "546546",
        }
    ]
},
]
```

Comment: First of all, your required output is not a valid JSON or `list`

Comment: Now check again

Answer (score 0):

```
  def get_invoice_data(self, inv_list, inv_key):

    invoices_list = []
    reg_invoices_list = []
    index=0
    new_dict = {}
    for index, each_invoice in enumerate(inv_list):

        new_dict['first_name'] = each_invoice.users.user.first_name
        new_dict['invoice_number'] = inv_key

    return {'invoices_list': invoices_list.appen(new_dict)}
```

Comment: Any changes in get_invoice_list() method?

Comment: response  --->   {
        "invoice_list": [
            {
                "invoices_list": null
            },
            {
                "invoices_list": null
            }
        ]
    }

Comment: can you pls check

Comment: Acually i want the response in dict not as a list.